# Updating Items in GridView through Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

I have a GV in which I want to Update my items. I am not using LDS or anything coz I m updating items which are stored in multiple databases.

Here is the markup of my GV:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" Height="233px" Width="602px" ID ="gvShowComm" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowEditing = "gvShowComm_RowEditing" 
        OnRowUpdating = "gvShowComm_RowUpdating" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit = "gvShowComm_RowCancelingEdit">

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowCancelButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Product ID">
         <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID = "ProductName" runat = "server" Text ='<%# Bind("Product_ID") %>'/>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID = "ProductName" runat = "server" Text ='<%# Bind("Product_ID") %>'/>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>


     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Plan Name">
         <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID = "PlanName" runat = "server" Text ='<%# Bind("PlanName") %>'/>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID = "PlanName" runat = "server" Text ='<%# Bind("PlanName") %>'/>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "1st Yr Comm">
         <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID = "HiComm" runat = "server" Text ='<%# Bind("HiCommissionOld") %>'/>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID = "HiComm" runat = "server" Text ='<%# Bind("HiCommissionOld") %>'/>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "2nd Yr Comm">
         <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID = "LowComm" runat = "server" Text ='<%# Bind("LowCommissionOld") %>'/>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID = "LowComm" runat = "server" Text ='<%# Bind("LowCommissionOld") %>'/>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" /> 
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is code I've been trying but I cant able to get the updated TEXT in my 's' variable:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["EntitySelected"] == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select an Entity first!");
            Response.Redirect("~/FrontEnd/AgentList.aspx");
        }

        int getEntity = Int16.Parse(Session["EntitySelected"].ToString());
        this.Label3.Text = "You Selected Entity: " + (string)Session["EntitySelected"];

        dbWebEnrollDataContext dt1 = new dbWebEnrollDataContext(); //This has PlanName!
        CommissionsV2DataContext cv1 = new CommissionsV2DataContext(); //Entity_Product_Point
        var td = from s in GetEntity()
                 join r in GetPlanName() on s.Product_ID equals r.Product_ID
                 where s.Entity_ID == getEntity
                 select new
                 {
                     s.Product_ID,
                     r.PlanName,
                     s.HiCommissionOld,
                     s.LowCommissionOld


                 };
        gvShowComm.DataSource = td;
        gvShowComm.DataBind();
    }

    static IEnumerable<Entity_Product_Point> GetEntity()
    {
        var context = new CommissionsV2DataContext();
        return (from t in context.Entity_Product_Points select t).AsQueryable();
    }

    static IEnumerable<PlanMaster> GetPlanName()
    {
        var context = new dbWebEnrollDataContext();
        return (from t in context.PlanMasters select t).AsQueryable();
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            if (ddlPlan.SelectedValue != null && tb1stYr.Text != "" && tbMaximum.Text != "" && tbRecurring.Text != "")
            {
                //Accessing Variables and defining them.
                using (dbWebEnrollDataContext dt = new dbWebEnrollDataContext())
                    try
                    {
                        int getEntity = Int16.Parse(Session["EntitySelected"].ToString());

                        var productName = ddlPlan.SelectedValue.ToString();

                        decimal firststYrComp = Int16.Parse(tb1stYr.Text.ToString());
                        decimal recurringComp = Int16.Parse(tbRecurring.Text.ToString());
                        decimal maximumPercent = Int16.Parse(tbMaximum.Text.ToString());

                        //Pulling the Product_ID from the PlanMaster Table from WebEnroll DB!

                        //var tr = dt.PlanMasters.First(s => s.PlanName == productName);

                        var tr = from s in dt.PlanMasters
                                 where s.PlanName == productName
                                 select s.Product_ID;

                        decimal finalFirstYrComp = decimal.Round((firststYrComp / maximumPercent), 3);
                        decimal finalRecurringComp = decimal.Round((recurringComp / maximumPercent), 3);

                        //Updating the Table: Entity_Product_Points in CommissionsV2 DB.
                        CommissionsV2DataContext cv = new CommissionsV2DataContext();
                        Entity_Product_Point ev = new Entity_Product_Point();
                        ev.Entity_ID = getEntity;
                        ev.Product_ID = tr.First();
                        ev.HiCommissionOld = (double)firststYrComp;
                        ev.LowCommissionOld = (double)recurringComp;
                        ev.HiCommission = (double)finalFirstYrComp * 100;
                        ev.LowCommission = (double)finalRecurringComp * 100;
                        ev.DateCreated = System.DateTime.Now;
                        cv.Entity_Product_Points.InsertOnSubmit(ev);
                        cv.SubmitChanges();

                        var td = from s in GetEntity()
                                 join r in GetPlanName() on s.Product_ID equals r.Product_ID
                                 where s.Entity_ID == getEntity
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     s.Product_ID,
                                     r.PlanName,
                                     s.HiCommissionOld,
                                     s.LowCommissionOld


                                 };

                        gvShowComm.DataSource = td;
                        gvShowComm.DataBind();

                    }

                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("" + err);
                    }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Entry for the textboxes!");
            }

            tb1stYr.Text = "";
            tbMaximum.Text = "";
            tbRecurring.Text = "";
            ddlPlan.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }


    protected void gvShowComm_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) 
    {
        gvShowComm.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        gvShowComm.DataBind();

    }

    protected void gvShowComm_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gvShowComm.EditIndex = -1;
        gvShowComm.DataBind();
    }

    protected void gvShowComm_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox myBox = gvShowComm.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("PlanName") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;
        string s = myBox.Text;
        gvShowComm.DataBind();
    }



    }
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: In anyway. I am commenting the different lines in the code, but none of them is picking the correct value from the GV. See my EDIT. I pasted the ERRORS also, if I m running them one by one...

Comment: Your code for `gvShowComm_RowUpdating` makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I want to access the selected row items. All I want to get the value. Which part you are not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ideas:
First, you can use Template Fields for your columns & name the control
    holding your data.  The contents of those controls can then be retrieved as follows: `((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBoxProductName")).Text`

The template would look something like this:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product_Name") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product_Name") %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Note also that because you are databinding the gridview manually, in the RowEditing (Not the RowUpdating) event fired by the edit button, you must set the gridview's edit index.  Try:

```
gvShowComm.EditIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
```

Or, second, you can have more than one datakey in a
    gridview.  Try something like:
    `DataKeyNames="Product_ID,Product_Name,Product_Price"`

Those values can then be retrieved as follows:

```
gvShowComm.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["Product_Name"]
```

I should note that DataKeys are only really designed to hold db primary keys.  Using them for anything else is a hack.  That said, I've had need for it occasionally when I need to store some piece of information for each row, but I don't want it visible to the user.

A final note, don't put the databinding in the page load unless you are putting it inside a conditional that only fires on initial page load, not every postback.  Ex: if(!IsPostback) ...

Comment: @Joseph: I tried with your code (1st one) and it worked :D Thank you. But now the problem is that they are not EDITABLE thru GView? Why is that?

Comment: You must put the gridview into edit mode. You'll need a column with an edit button. Easiest way is to add an "Edit, Update, Cancel" CommandField from the GUI. The result will be a column with an "Edit" link button with the CommandType="Edit" attribute. That attribute means clicking it will fire the GridView's RowEditing event. If you are using a datasource object to populate the gridview it will handle that event automatically. If you are populating the gridview manually, you will have to handle the event. Also, if using Template Fields for your columns, you must have an EditItem Template.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. All the things you said, it there. I have en 'Edit' button and it is firing the RowUpdating event. And YES I am populating GView manually thru code behind. Now I m using Template Fields for my columns..Where should I put EditItem Template?

Comment: I got the EditItem Template. But the items are not showing in this template.

Comment: See my edit above.  Because you are databinding manually, you must set the gridview edit index manually in the RowEditing event handler.

Comment: There is no option for e.row! I am doing this though:             gvShowComm.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

Comment: Can you post the full markup of your gridview.  Are you trying to allow the user to edit or are you trying to edit directly from the codebehind?

Comment: Also include the full contents of your RowUpdating & RowEditing event handlers.

Comment: That's not the full markup.  I don't see the opening tag for the gridview.  I also don't see your RowEditing event handler (the one that contains the gvShowComm.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex; code

Comment: @ Joseph: Changed, sorry about that.

Comment: I don't think you need to databind your gridview again in the RowEditing event handler.  Have you put a breakpoint in there to ensure it is actually getting hit?

Comment: So it never even displays your textboxes?  What is it doing exactly?

Comment: It is showing me this err as soon I click on 'Update' Link: Multiple controls with the same ID 'ProductName' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Comment: Take a look at your markup.  You have the IDs for the labels & textboxes ALL set to "ProductName".  It looks to me like they should have IDs like "TextBoxProduct_ID", "LabelProduct_ID", "TextBoxPlanName", "LabelPlanName" etc.  Basically, each one should have a unique ID.

Comment: Thanks man. That was dumb mistake. Now I want to access the controls of that. How should I go ahead?

Comment: You'll want to do that in the RowUpdating event handler after the user clicks the update button.  Use the find control method, cast the result as a textbox & use it as you would a text box: ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBoxProductName")).Text

Comment: Seems like this is also not working:             TextBox tb1 = this.gvShowComm.Rows[this.gvShowComm.EditIndex].FindControl("PlanName") as TextBox;

Comment: Can you post your current RowUpdating event handler in full?

Comment: it should be `gvShowComm.Rows[e.RoWIndex].FindControl("PlanName") as TextBox;`

Comment: @Joseph: dont abuse DataKeyNames. Ideally, its for storing primary keys of a table. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx

Comment: Did that. Please have a look :)

Comment: @Yet: I did that it is giving me ambiguous err.

Comment: @All: I am seeing two times the columns. I can see that I am fetching from the LINQ Query from Page_Load. But I want to show my columns only once!

Comment: Make sure you have the AutoGenerateColumns attribute of the gridview set to false

Comment: pal, do these things. inside grids markup make Product_ID the only datakeyname. also give separate ids for itemtemplate and edititemtemplate

Comment: @Joseph: Glad that worked. Now how do I get the access of the control?

Comment: @Dot With the FindControl code posted above. If you are still getting an error, please post it.  BTW, @Yet is correct...using DataKeys for anything other than primary keys is a hack, and you don't seem to need it in your situation.

Comment: @Jos: If I m writing this:                         System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox t1 = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("PlanName")).Text;

Comment: Its not working and giving me an err on e.Row. Error 1 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I just looked at your edited code above & it looks like you are trying to access e.Row in PageLoad.  What exactly are you trying to do?  My assumption is something like this: Load Grid (PageLoad) --> user clicks edit button on row -> put grid into edit mode (RowEditing) -> user makes changes in text boxes --> user clicks update button -> you try to retrieve value from textboxes (RowUpdating) & use the updated value to make changes in your data source.  Correct?             BTW, your statement directly above is attempting to force a string (.Text) into a TextBox object.

Comment: Did you try the code that @Yet posted: `TextBox myBox = gvShowComm.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("PlanName") AS TextBox;`  If that works then you can use `myBox.Text` to get the value entered by the user.  This will only work in the RowUpdating event though.  I'm not sure why you are trying to access e.Row in the PageLoad.

Comment: @Joseph Schrag: BTW,+1 and welcome to Stack Overflow. Dont get hooked :P

Comment: @Joesph and Yet: Thanks for all your comments. I really appreciate your views. I wrote this code which 'Yet' mentioned: System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox myBox = gvShowComm.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("PlanName") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;
            string s = myBox.Text;

Comment: When I am checking through a breakpoint I cannot see edited text in 's' variable. It is showing OLD text which was showing previously.

Comment: @Joseph: I edited my answer. I am not accessing e.Row in Page_Load.

Comment: @dot Please post your updated code - specifically the RowUpdating event handler in its entirety.

Comment: @dot Could be a result of databinding your gridview on every page load.  Try putting that inside a conditional: if (!IsPostback) do databind.  Or, better yet, move the databinding to it's own method & call it from that conditional (if statement) in the page load.

Comment: @Joseph: I added you on my LinkedIN network. Would like to add you on my professional network. Hope you would not mind. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @dot Looks like you got the problem fixed as you marked an answer, correct?  Also, be sure to give @yetanothercoder a vote as he was also very involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the property `DataKeyNames="Product_ID"` in the GridViews Markup, you will get the value of Product_ID on RowUpdating as,

```
var keyValue = gvShowComm.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
int product = Convert.ToInt32(keyValue);
```

Comment: How to write if I have more DataKeyName? Like: Product_ID, PlanName...etc.

Comment: When I am writing your code, it is working fine. But the columns is NOT editable from GV. I can now get the value into the variable product, but the column Product_ID is not editable now...Why?

Comment: was away. pal, both are very different issues. why dont you analyse what aint working and split it into sections and analyse and split ... till you find whats wrong?