# Updating GridView through code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

I am having a GV (which I am populating through code behind) in which I want to UPDATE the items the row that I selected in.

Here is what I am populating in my GView:

```
  var td = from s in GetEntity()
                 join r in GetPlanName() on s.Product_ID equals r.Product_ID
                 where s.Entity_ID == getEntity
                 select new
                 {
                     s.Product_ID,
                     r.PlanName,
                     s.HiCommissionOld,
                     s.LowCommissionOld


                 };
        gvShowComm.DataSource = td;
        gvShowComm.DataBind();
```

Here is the mark up of my GV:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" Height="233px" Width="602px" ID ="gvShowComm" 
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    EnableViewState="False" OnRowEditing = "gvShowComm_RowEditing" 
    OnRowUpdating = "gvShowComm_RowUpdating" 
    OnRowCancelingEdit = "gvShowComm_RowCancelingEdit" 
    DataKeyNames = "Product_ID" >



    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowCancelButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

And here is my Code Behind:

```
 protected void gvShowComm_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
          int index = gvShowComm.EditIndex;
        GridViewRow row = gvShowComm.Rows[index];
        string name = row.Cells[2].Text; //name is empty!
    }
```

So here is my problem: I can access one column through DataKeyNames property in my GView tag, but I have to access other elements in order to UPDATE my Grid View through LINQ in the code behind. The reason why I am NOT using LDS because I am updating tables from 2 different databases.

Thank you!

Comment: so you're just trying to figure out how to access other column information in the rowupdating handler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Items in GridView through Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597737/updating-items-in-gridview-through-code)

Comment: Please stop posting comments as answers.  This is not a forum, it is a question and answer site.  If you need to post more information about your question, edit your question to add the additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the other cells in the row like this. Take a [look at this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows.aspx) for more details.

```
gvShowComm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[index]
```